# How can I tell TFS to give me the entire project how it was at THIS specific changeset?

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I'm using Eclipse with the TFS plugin and I used Team -> Get Latest Version and it download some newer additions from my colleague. Now some of his code isn't working and I can no longer build the application to test because of the errors in his code.

How can I tell the client to download the Entire application from TFS at THIS SPECIFIC changeset? For example, I submitted a Check in when everything was working. I want to return to that state of the application. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a TFS or SVN question? You mention the TFS plugin, and SVN in the title of the question?

Comment: TFS, I was under the impression they were one and the same.

Comment: They are both version control systems, one is by Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx) , the other is Open Source (http://subversion.apache.org)

Answer (score 1):

You can update to a specific revision. If you know the revision of your stable check in, it's not too difficult to do an update. I'm not familiar with TFS, though.

The command line details [are here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re28.html)

You probably need something like

```
svn update -r30
```

If you already checked out the bad code (and it sound like you did), you can do a revert to revision. This action reverse merges the changes out of your code. I'm less familiar with that...

Answer (score 1):

For TFS with the Eclipse plug-in installed...

If you right click on the project in Package Explorer and select "Team, View History..." you'll be able to see what changeset your colleagues bad check-in occured (i.e. the number in the left-most column).  Make a note of the changeset (for example 1338).

You want to revert you project to the state before this change was made.  Therefore you want badChangeset-1, i.e. if the bad changeset was 1338, you want 1337.

To get this you can right click on the project and go to "Team, Get Specific Version...", select "Changeset" and type the changeset number you want (i.e. 1337).

Alternatively, if you just wanted to get an older version of one or two broken files then you could do "Team, View History..." on the file and then when you see the version you want of that file right click on it in the history view and select "Get this version...".

Hope that helps,

Martin.

Answer (score 0):

Josh is Right.

For the GUI-approach Rightclick Project > Team > Show History > scroll to what the checkin you want, select and use the command "switch to revision" or "update to revision".

For Problems like yours you might want first to commit your own changes somewhere just to be sure nothing is lost. If the trunk is broken there is not much additional damage you can do by checking in ;).

Then going back revisions in steps often helped me to find the exact checkin that caused the problem.

good luck.